# Difference between Grunt SASS task properties options, dist and dev?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

As I am editing the sass task of my Gruntfile.js I don't understand the difference between the different properties (e.g. `dist`, `dev` and `options`) of the `sass` task object.

For example, in the code below the `sass` object contains two properties, `options` and `dist`. I have also seen a `dev` property in some other examples of the `sass` task.

```
sass: {
    options: {
      includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
    },
    dist: {
      options: {
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
      },
      files: {
        'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss',
        // our component file on the right
        // file to save on the left
        'css/top-bar.css' : 'scss/topbar.scss'
      }
    }
  },
```

At the grunt-sass Github documentation only the `options` property is discussed. There is no mention of `dist` and `dev` but I see that `options` can appear in `dist` and `dev`. Logic tells me that `dist` is for the final build and that `dev` is for development. I'm not sure though and also not sure how to use them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring a task, you can have many targets, like `dist` or `dev` (you can name them whatever you want). Each target can have its own settings, which obviously depends on the task.

I'm not sure which task you're using (maybe [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass)?), but the outermost `options` is probably applied to all targets.

See [this part](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) of Grunt's documentation.

Comment: and yes I'm using grunt-sass